# Wordpress - outputting relevent posts in sidebar.php on selected posts

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

This seems like something that should be really easy, I want to output the latest three events when on an event post and the latest three news items when on a news post, I've got this working in a very basic sense however I can work out how to do the following:

When on a post in events show the latest three events, when on a post in news show the latest three news posts. I've looked on here http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags and thought that is_category('news') and is_category('events') would do the trick however these conditionals seem to only be available on category archive pages.

I currently have the following code which simple checks you're on a single post page (I'm only using posts for news and events, everything else is a page):

```
<?php 
  if ( is_single() ) {
    query_posts('category_name=news&order=DSC&offset=1&orderby=ID&posts_per_page=2'); 
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <article>
      <h3><a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
      <span class="date"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></span>
      <?php the_excerpt($strip_teaser); ?>
      <a class="more" href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'>Read more</a>
    </article>

    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?>

  <?php 
  }
  else {

  }

  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional comments should work, you were just one letter off (in vs. is)

You want `in_category()`, not `is_category()`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/in_category